# Azure Devops pipeline, multi branch trigger doesn't work

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, git-repo

I'm working for the first time with Azure Devops Pipelines. I'm using a .yml file. But I can't figure out why the pipeline won't run when I checkout and push a branch from develop to "releases/*. It just won't trigger even when there are changes in `src/` which are inside my new `releases/newbranch`

But when I merge my change from "customers/feature-branch" with `customers/moa-prototype-client1/release` the pipeline will run.

My trigger is:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - customers/moa-prototype-client1/release
    - releases/* 
  paths:
    include:
    - src/*
    - src/customers/moa-prototype-client1/*
    exclude:
    - '*.yml'
    - src/customers/*
```

What can cause this?

So in short: It will trigger when I merge from `Customers/Customername/Develop` to `Customers/Customername/Release`. But won't when I merge from `Develop` to `Releases/*`

Our repo:[Gitflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqE87.png)

Comment: It may be similar issue to this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102880/azure-devops-ci-pipeline-for-master-being-triggered-by-changes-in-branch-and-vic/59107351#59107351 check my answer with overriding yaml example.

Comment: You can find more information what could go wrong here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#faq  Check case-sensitivity too.

Comment: @Kontekst thanks for your reply, It was an user error there was an "space" behind the trigger.. I think this was causing the problem. It all works fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: After checking the links and possible solution some users suggested, I got it to work. But I was not totaly happy whit this fix, because I wanted to run my pipeline though my .yml file and not override my triggers though the pipeline settings.

When I looked at my .yml again and noticed a space behind `releases/*`, I removed this space and committed this to my repo and all was working as it should!

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that this issue exists in the `Release/*` branch. And the `customers branch` could work as expected.

During my testing, I encounter a similar situation. If the `Release/*` branch doesn't contain the Yaml file with triggers, the changes in the release branches will not trigger the build.

For example:

Doesn't work

[image: No Yaml file]

To solve this issue, you could copy the same yaml file from other branches to all release branches.

[image: Contain Yaml file]

Then the changes in the Release branches could trigger the build successfully.

On the other hand, as Kontekst said, the Path filters are case-sensitive. You could check them at the same time.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the yml file is available in every branch. I this case it was an user error.. some how there was a space behind my trigger. now everything is working fine :)